# std::condition_variable wait_for infinite

Tags: c++, c++11, synchronization, wait, condition-variable

I am trying to make an infinite wait on the condition variable with the following code (just a sample to display the issue):

```
std::condition_variable cond;
std::mutex mtx;
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
cond.wait_for(lock, std::chrono::steady_clock::duration::max());
```

But the wait exits straight away. Digging a little deeper into the (MS) implementation of `wait_for` I've found that it actually uses `wait_until` function. But before that it converts the time using a call to `chrono::system_clock::now()` and just adding the duration.

And of course this leads to integer overflow so the new time becomes <= 'now'. Thus `wait_until` exits immediately.
The same happens to all other timed wait functions (e.g. `try_lock_for` in `std::timed_mutex` class).

Summurazing the above, I would like to ask if this is a bug in the implementation of the timed wait functions and if so then where can I write about it?

Also, since `wait_until` uses `system_clock`, actual wait time should vary if there were time adjustments during the wait (because `system_clock` is not monotonic). Thus there is no trust to wait duration.

Comment: Have you considered using the [wait](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait) function instead?  That waits without a timer.

Comment: IMHO, it is a [spurious wakeup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup).

Comment: @megabyte1024 it's not spurious, since it is easily reproducible.
Also the return value from wait function is "timed out", so there is no wakeup at all

Comment: @megabyte1024 also if you set the waiting time to some less extreme values, like 10 seconds or so, waiting will occur

Comment: @ArtyomChirkov, probably it is a issue in the implementation. But important to understand that all `std::condition_variable` `wait` methods may be unblocked spuriously. And the only correct way to use `wait` functions, which have no predicate as the parameter, is to "wrap" a loop with an own variable between a mutex lock and the wait method call, inside of the loop. In this case the 'easy to use' methods are `wait` and `wait_until`.

Comment: @megabyte1024 wrapping won't help - you can verify this yourself. The wait wil just constantly exit with timeout

Comment: @ArtyomChirkov, I understood and wrote that probably it is an issue. My idea is that using of `wait_for` is not best solution.

Answer (score 0):

The [cppreference documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_for) says:

> Note that `rel_time` must be small enough not to overflow when added to `std::chrono::steady_clock::now()`.

And:

> The clock tied to timeout_time is used, which is not required to be a monotonic clock.There are no guarantees regarding the behavior of this function if the clock is adjusted discontinuously, but the existing implementations convert timeout_time from Clock to `std::chrono::system_clock` and delegate to POSIX `pthread_cond_timedwait` so that the wait honors ajustments to the system clock, but not to the the user-provided Clock. In any case, the function also may wait for longer than until after `timeout_time` has been reached due to scheduling or resource contention delays.
>
> Even if the clock in use is `std::chrono::steady_clock` or another monotonic clock, a system clock adjustment may induce a spurious wakeup.

If you want an infinite timeout you can just do something like this (not tested):

```
wait_until(lock, std::chrono::sys_time::max());
```